# Get named list of rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my script I am joining multiple rooms and that work just great.

Server:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("join", function(room) {
       socket.join(room);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
socket.emit("join", "website");
socket.emit("join", "user");
socket.emit("join", "front");
```

However if I try to list them via `io.rooms` I get a strange object consisting of empty key and a array of rooms but with their IDs (I guess), not their name.

```
{ '':
   [ 'FcETdaJ3P4R-IyGdevLj',
     '9Qv2tEe3-IrKleFSevLk',
     'F6G6nq5r8lM_nI-ievLl' ] }
```

How do I retrieve a named list of rooms with connected user count, e.g.:

```
{
    "website": 6,
    "front": 4,
    "user": 1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`io.rooms` is the correct way to list the rooms. The keys in the object are the name of the rooms, the array is the id's of the connected clients. `''` is the default room, so it seems that no one has connected to any room when you try log them.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `io.sockets.manager.rooms` will give you a object with the global room, all other rooms, and the IDs of clients in those rooms.

```
console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms);

rooms: {
  '': [
    'IDJYUhL2RMNGiulk5Aii'
  ],
  'room1': [
    'IDJYUhL2RMNGiulk5Aii',
    'dTtHIdIzSfV96kbu5Aij'
  ],
  'room2': [
    'dTtHIdIzSfV96kbu5Aij'
  ]
}
```

So to get the count of users, just use `length()` on the user list.